# KeyPressEvent in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a application for maping some keyboard shortcuts to some event. So, I need detecting the keyboard shortcuts pressed after clicking a button. For Example, I have a button having text on it "change". When I click on it text on it changes to "press keys" then I need the user to type the shortcut keys he want to map then the text of the button changes to the keys pressed.
While surfing the net, I was only able to find the function :

```
  void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
  {
  ...
  }
```

but it doesn't fulfill my purpose as I need calling this function from the slot function defined so that I can detect only when I need.
Anybody having any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 6):

You could set a state variable that indicates that the user pressed the button. The window is then supposed to react to the next keyPressEvent (only when this state variable is set) and resets the state variable afterwards.

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (process_key) {
        /* Do whatever needs to be done */
        process_key = false
    }
}
```